# Can I set a different .net version for a new AppDomain?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, appdomain

If my .net executable runs under .net version 4 can I create a new AppDomain and run other assemblies under .net 2?

Comment: why do you want this?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525325/is-it-possible-to-load-an-assembly-targeting-a-different-net-runtime-version-in